# Is there a big picture view of what developers are working on across many projects in Jira?

Tags: jira

There are currently many projects within Jira.  Some developers might have tasks or issues across those projects.  Is there a big picture view with Jira or Grasshopper which shows all developers and what they are working on?

Alternatively, is there a way to see all projects along with the number of tasks being worked on for each of them?  We are currently using Jira and Grasshopper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a gadget - '[Issues in Progress](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Adding+the+In+Progress+Gadget)' which shows all issues with 'In Progress' status along all projects. But it does not sort data by developer.

You may find a better use out of '[Two Dimensional Filter Statistics](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Adding+the+Two-Dimensional+Filter+Statistics+Gadget)' gadget with 'All Issues in Progress' filter (which you need to create if you don't have one already) and use Assignee/Project as Axis data.

You can also use '[Activity stream](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Adding+the+Activity+Stream+Gadget)' for all projects to see latest activity.